# How to find the transliteration of a (Attic) Greek word?

Tags: ancient-greek, greek-translation, greek-to-english-translation, greek-to-latin-translation

Is there a way to find the transliteration of a (Attic) Greek word in English/Latin? Also called Romanization of a Greek word, I guess?

Is there a dictionary that provides the transliteration of each Greek word?

I am not able to type Greek words with accentuation and breathing, so let me give an example in the following screenshot. Is the transliteration of the Greek word "sun"?

[image]

Are the transliterations of the following two Greek words "o" and "O"?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

There isn't really such a thing as *the* transliteration of a Greek word—there are a few different transliteration conventions in common use. The main one you'll see is a kind of informal standard similar to [ISO 843](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_843), and another one you may find useful to be aware of is [Beta Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Code), which was once more common but now is pretty much only used by [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph).

| Greek | ISO 843-ish | Beta Code | other renderings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| α | a, ā | a |  |
| β | b | b |  |
| γ | g | g |  |
| δ | d | d |  |
| ε | e | e |  |
| ζ | z | z | zd, dz, zz |
| η | ē | h | e, eh, ê |
| θ | th | q | tʰ |
| ι | i | i |  |
| κ | k | k |  |
| λ | l | l |  |
| μ | m | m |  |
| ν | n | n |  |
| ξ | x | c | ks |
| ο | o | o |  |
| π | p | p |  |
| ρ | r | r | rh (with rough breathing) |
| σ/ς | s | s |  |
| τ | t | t |  |
| υ | u | u | y (very rare for Ancient Greek, common for Modern) |
| φ | ph | f | pʰ |
| χ | ch | x | kʰ, kh |
| ψ | ps | y |  |
| ω | ō | w | o, ow, ô |
| ◌̔ | h | ( | ʰ, (nothing) |
| ◌̓ | (nothing) | ) |  |
| ◌́ | ◌́ | / |  |
| ◌̀ | ◌̀ | \ |  |
| ◌̃ | ◌̂ | = |  |
| ◌ͅ | i, (nothing) | | |  |

(Note that Beta Code originally used capital letters; Perseus doesn't. Accents are often omitted in transliterations because anglophones find them hard to type.)

Besides these two, many people have their idiosyncratic systems that differ in minor ways. For your own use, the important thing is to pick a system that conveys the information you want to convey (e.g. don't use ô for ω if you're also using the circumflex as an accent) and to use it consistently.

You won't find any dictionaries dedicated to transliterations, because transliteration of Greek is a very trivial thing. Most translation dictionaries won't bother to include transliterations for the same reason, but e.g. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%8D%CE%BD) does have them.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [beta code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Code). This was the default way of representing Greek since the 80s, and it was even used by the TLG, the default ancient Greek digital search tool.

You can see TLG's official version here: https://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/encoding.php

You can also turn beta code into polytonic Greek here: https://www.translatum.gr/converter/beta-code.htm

Comment: Beta code is a romanization scheme, but it isn't meant to "transcribe" in the way that the OP seems to be looking for.